# How to translate this grpc call to a native PHP call using grpc pecl extension?

Tags: php, grpc

I am using **PHP 7.0.10 on Windows Server** and I recently installed the [PECL grpc extension](https://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/grpc/1.9.0/) because I would like to migrate a call like this one:

```
$output = shell_exec('grpcurl.exe -insecure -proto extranet.proto -d {\"Usuario\":\"user\",\"Senha\":\"pass\"} www.jucerja.rj.gov.br:9443 extranet.v0.BuscaEmpresa/Login 2>&1');
print_r($output);
```

to a native one using the grpc extension.

I even tried this lib: https://packagist.org/packages/grpc/grpc and this code:

```
<?php
    
include 'vendor/autoload.php';

use \Grpc\BaseStub;
use \Grpc\ChannelCredentials;

$stub = new class extends BaseStub{
    
    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct("www.jucerja.rj.gov.br:9443", [
            'credentials'=> ChannelCredentials::createInsecure()
        ]);
    }
    
    function serializeToString() {
        return new class {
            function serializeToString(){
                return '{"Usuario":"user","Senha":"pass"}';
            }
        };
    }
    
    function login($deserialize){
        $this->_simpleRequest('extranet.v0.BuscaEmpresa/Login', $this->serializeToString(), $deserialize);
    }
};

$stub->login(function($data){
    var_dump($data);
});
```

But the result was empty !

So, how can I achieve the same result of shell_exec but using php_grpc?

Comment: Of course, you have enabled PHP warnings so that you can see any error messages?

Comment: @Olivier added ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL) and nothing has change, unfortunately

Comment: Did you write the code manually or did you generate it?

Comment: @Olivier manually because I am not able to run generator on this windows server. But I have the .proto file

Comment: You should really try to generate the code. What's the problem with the generator? Also you can do the generation on another machine, it doesn't have to be the same.

Answer (score -1):

I would really suggest that you generate the code on some machine. It doesn't have to be the actual server where you are going to run the code. Here is an example for you:

```
php ./vendor/bin/protobuf --include-descriptors -i . -o ./src/ ./extranet.proto
```

From:
https://github.com/protobuf-php/protobuf-plugin